# Transition effect creating a bug

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am working on a horizontal dropdown navigation menu. I am using a transition to slow it down, but I've hit a bug. If you jump too fast (before the transition completes?) from one nav item to the other, you are still shown the other dropdown menu. It's a bit hard to explain - but I've created a CodePen.

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something basic... all feedback is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**CodePen link:** https://codepen.io/zp12345/pen/mQzvXr

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-links">
  <ul class="nav-primary" id="nav-primary">
    <li class="nav-item-top">
      <a href="#link">
        <span class="nav-item-label">Item One</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
          <a href="#link">
            <h5>1.1</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
          <a href="#link">
            <h5>1.2</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item-top">
      <a href="#link">
        <span class="nav-item-label">Item Two</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
          <a href="#link">
            <h5>2.1</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
          <a href="#link">
            <h5>2.2</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item-top">
      <a href="#link">
        <span class="nav-item-label">Item Three</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
          <a href="#link">
            <h5>3.1</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
          <a href="#link">
            <h5>3.2</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item-top">
      <a href="#link">
        <span class="nav-item-label">Item Four</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li class="nav-dropdown-item">
          <a href="#link">
            <h5>4.1</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.nav-primary {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1; 
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-item-top .nav-item-label {
  color: #383838;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-item-top {
  &:hover {
    .nav-item-label {
      color: #319644;
    }
    .nav-dropdown {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      padding: 16px 0;
    }
  }
}
.nav-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  transition: .2s;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #133751;
  color: #133751;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  .nav-dropdown-item {
    transition: .2s;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer!important;
  }
  h5 {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
.nav-dropdown-item {
  a {
    transition: all 0.2s;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi - did you know you can embed HTML and CSS directly into your quesiton? Although - it doesn't support SCSS - you'd have to transpile it - which yo8u can do here: https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: I've tested your CodePen, and the menus works very well, the bug you are talking about is normal, but Who would feel so bored and would play with the menus to change so fast between them? I think the menus works great, if you want to get another result just play with the CSS. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transition-delay:0.2s;` on hover when you show the `.nav-dropdown`. That will not show the dropdown when you move mouse fast.

You can test it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQQjBO)